# Two tomcat in same server - Upstart Script Ubuntu Server

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, digital-ocean, upstart

I installed two versions of the tomcat on my server, I followed the [DigitalOcean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04), that teaches how to install and configures upstart script, but I need have two versions of the Tomcat 7 and 8.

The Tomcat 8 was installed on following path:

```
/opt/tomcat
```

And Tomcat 7

```
/opt/tomcat7
```

I followed every step about installation. Tomcat 8 works fine on port 8080 but tomcat 7 don't works.

Edited

When I try to run the `"sudo initctl start tomcat7"` the follow message is displayed `"tomcat7 start/running, process 24621"` but when try restart `"sudo initctl restart tomcat7"` the message is `initctl: Unknown instance:`

I Have been tested the script `init-checkconf /etc/init/tomcat7.conf`  and it is ok `File /etc/init/tomcat7.conf: syntax ok`

```
http://myIp:8080 tomcat 8 is ok
http://myIp:8081 tomcat 7 dont't open on browser
```

I believe that my config is not right.

**Tomcat 8 config:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

  </Service>
</Server>
```

/etc/init/tomcat.conf

```
description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat
  setgid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

  # Modify these options as needed
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
  env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```

And...

**Tomcat 7 config:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8444" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" />

  </Service>
</Server>
```

/etc/init/tomcat7.conf

```
description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat
  setgid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat7

  # Modify these options as needed
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
  env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```

Somebody know how to make the correctly installation, thanks in advance!

Comment: "tomcat 7 don't works" -- care to elaborate?

Comment: @mindas, sorry but I did not understand!

Comment: You said "tomcat 7 don't works" -- can you provide details? How does it fail, is there an error message or anything?

Comment: @mindas, I updated my question! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the tomcat logs to see if Tomcat 7 starts up correctly?

Comment: @Mike, thanks! I checked now and /opt/tomcat7/logs/ is empty

Comment: So the next step would be to look to see if the process that `initctl` reports as started is really started and, if so, whether it is actually Tomcat7. If not, then it would be time to try to run Tomcat7 in the same way that `initctl` is trying to to see if there is any error message printed to the console.

Comment: @Mike, I ran the manual mode and work: sudo /opt/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the manual mode and work:

```
sudo /opt/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```

> Using CATALINA_BASE: /opt/tomcat7 Using CATALINA_HOME: /opt/tomcat7
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7/temp Using JRE_HOME: /usr Using
>   CLASSPATH:
>   /opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar Tomcat
>   started.

feel free to reopen this question if necessary!

thanks!

Comment: The Upstart scripts in your question run `startup.sh` as the **tomcat** user (That's what the `setuid tomcat` stanza does). Your command in this answer runs the `startup.sh` script as **root**. As [other people have pointed out](http://serverfault.com/a/136015/219771), **this is unsafe**. Try running `sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh` instead.